# Android: How to open notification sound settings menu in

Tags: android, menu, audio, notifications

I am writing an application which uses notifications. I want to offer the
user an option to change the default  notification sound from the device sound
settings menu programmatically. for that i'm using:
`startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 0);`
the problem is, that the sound settings menu opens but I can not find a way to actually open the notification sound item.
Is there any way this could be done?
Thanks,
joel

Answer (score 1):

You have written very correct.

We can open Settings -> Sound and Notification Menu via

**startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 0);**

I am editing my answer, yes we cann open sub menu through the Action which is to be passed in Intent();

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean open the pop up menu for notification ringtone selection?
if so i am not sure there's way

Comment: yes. this is what I mean. isn't there a way to somehow programmatically press this menu item?